# Andriod Studio pixle 6 PRO there is a hole in the upper left corner

Tags: android-emulator

I do n’t know why, there is a hole in the upper left corner of this simulation mobile phone. Normally, there is only a middle camera. This problem is that I have opened the simulator. Many of my partners have the same question. There is only one interface for the skin of the phone, I don't know if this is a bug. In order to solve the problem of no skin, I also deliberately loaded the skin of the mobile phone, otherwise the option that selected the skin was incomparable. Are there any people with the same problem?

I tried to change a mobile phone skin, but it didn't work. The hole was still there. I searched a lot of information on the Internet, but good I did not have the same problem, but friends around me would have it.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue as you, funny bug. I solved it by deleting line 16 "cutout hole" in the file named "layout" in the skin folder.

Comment: Nice workaround, I hope android studio will fix this soon

Comment: What is the name of the skin folder, please?

Answer (score 3):

Delete the "Cutout hole" parameter in the device skin layout file line 16

You can access the skin folder by clicking on "Edit AVD(pen icon)" -> show advanced settings -> "..." (three dots next to "Device Frame") but its generally around /Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/skins/pixel_6_pro/layout

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. What I did was delete the AVD and create a new one (same phone, API 33) but with no frame. Then I booted it up normally and stopped it. After that I enabled the skin and the hole is gone now.

[screenshot of AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Ipl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it in the emulated device by enabling developer mode (7 taps on "Build Number") and then selecting "Device default" under "Display cutout".