# Is there a way to remove the annoying black circle when using an android emulator in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

[Android Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZdw.png)

I was planning to use an android device emulator since I cannot use my physical one but I suddenly encountered this black round circle and I find it annoying, is there any way to remove this? Last time I used the android device emulator, it wasn't there.

I tried disabling the camera and skin of android device but it's still there.

Comment: What device are you emulating?

Comment: Pixel Xl. I tried different devices, but the black circle is still there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74794584/andriod-studio-pixle-6-pro-there-is-a-hole-in-the-upper-left-corner

Comment: But that's the camera. It's pretty relevant if you want to test UX...

Comment: @zgc7009 thank you for this link! it solved my problem. I thought I was the only one who wasn't satisfied with the cutout hole.

Comment: @Pieterjan yes, but i think the camera would still function without it.

Answer (score 1):

Device Manager > Edit > Show Advance settings > Custom Skin Definition
go to the emulator path >

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\pixel_7_pro)

> open layout using notepad > remove cutout hole in the layout file save it and close it.
> Delete your device and create it again > done

Answer (score 1):

Editing the skin files did not work for me.  What did work was to open the Developer options (in the emulator's android settings) and change the value of "Display cutout" to "Device default"

Answer (score 0):

First, Delete the emulator, then Delete the "Cutout hole" parameter in the device skin layout file line 16

You can access the skin folder by clicking on "Edit AVD (pen icon)" -> show advanced settings -> "..." (three dots next to "Device Frame") but its generally around /Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/skins/pixel_6_pro/layout